# Why does my excel spreadsheet freezes when it finishes running the VBA code for copy & paste data from another workbook in next row available?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have this code to browse files from another workbook (named: "quote")
After copying the data I paste it  into the ("budget" workbook) on sheet1 (named: "data")
When I click the "Import quote" button, and it finishes copy & paste the data on the next available row, the spreadsheet freezes and I´m not allowed to click on any cell nor button.  Only when I minimize the workbook and enlarge it again it works. I want.

Why does my excel spreadsheet freezes when it finishes running the following code? :

Sub Get_Data_From_File()

```
Dim FiletoOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


FiletoOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse your File & Import Range", Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
If FiletoOpen <> False Then
   Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FiletoOpen)
   OpenBook.Sheets(2).Range("A2:i2").Copy
'---------------------------------------------------------
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")

Dim nextRow As Integer
nextRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
If nextRow = 0 Then nextRow = 1

'--------------------------------------------------------

ws.Range("A" & nextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
OpenBook.Close False
Sheets(1).Range("A" & nextRow).Select


'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA").Range("A6:i6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'OpenBook.Close False

   
   End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!

Comment: Side note: it is impossible for `nextRow` to be equal to `0`, so you can omit `If nextRow = 0 Then nextRow = 1`. `ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1` will never return `0`, there is no row 0 to begin with.

Comment: Thank you very much BigBen. So how can I make the code look for the next available row to fill in the "filetoopen" data?   Thank you very much :)

Comment: Just get rid of `If nextRow = 0 Then nextRow = 1`

Comment: It woked just fine! Thank you very much!! :)